# how do I make a device connect to several device where one device act as a admin?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a app where anybody can create a hub. One who creates a hub is now the admin of hub. He can search for YouTube videos and add them to a playlist. Other users can search for different hub and connect to it and they will see a same playlist created by admin and same video is being played on all devices connected to same hub.The thing is there is a voting system where users can vote for a specific video in playlist,the video with highest votes is played next

Thanks thing is I want to use firebase to implement this. Can anybody just guide me through how to implement this? I know the playlist has to be send to databse where other users can also see it. I just need to know steps or ideas how to implement it, any links or suggestions or other alternatives is highly appreciated?

Comment: What is a hub ?

Comment: It just a concept in the app. It's like creating a group where creator is the admin

Comment: You should tell more. Come to the point. Dont understand a word.

Comment: Its supposed to be like a group and different users can connect to this group. The main aim of this group is that everybody will be seeing the same youtube video , but only admin can add videos to the playlist where one song ends and the next song in playlist begins. Whenever the admin adds to playlist, the updated playlist should be seen in every connected device. I am a rookie pls guide me as to how I may achieve it. Any links or ideas or alternatives is just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an admin create a HUB, you need to create :

```
1. AdminHubDB :
     -$hubId1 :
       - adminId : $userid1
     -$hubId2 :
       - adminId : $userid2

2. MemberHubDB :
     -$hubId1 :
        - $userid1 : true
     -$hubId2 :
        - $userid1 : true
        - $userid2 : true

3. HubJoinedDB :
     -$userId1 :
          - $hubId1 : true
          - $hubId2 : true
     -$userId2 :
          - $hubid2 : true

4. PlayListDB :
     -$hubId1 :
          - $videoId1 :
                - videoUrl : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[SOMEID]
                - voteCount : 2
          - $videoId2 :
                - videoUrl : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[SOMEID]
                - voteCount : 1
     -$hubId2 :
          - $videoId3 :
                - videoUrl : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[SOMEID]
                - voteCount : 5
          - $videoId4 :
                - videoUrl : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[SOMEID]
                - voteCount : 10
```

For security purpose, you need to specify some rules :

1. Only Admin of Hub can write playlistDB
2. Only Member of Hub can vote to certain Video

Here is the rule :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "PlayListDB": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$hubId": {
        ".write": "root.child('AdminHubDB/'+$hubId+'/adminId'+'/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        "$videoId" :{
          "voteCount" :{
            ".write" : "root.child('MemberHubDB/'+$hubId+'/'+auth.uid).exists()"
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

If parent's rule equals true, it will ignore child's rule, event if the child's rule is false.

But if parent's rule equals false, it will continue to examine the rule of the child.

And also, when you updating voteCount make sure you're using Firebase transaction method for valid count

Comment: How do I specify these rules?Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Abhinav422 there, i've updated my answer